# The problem of configuring the libfptr10 driver in linux (Russian cash register equipment)

Tags: json, linux, string, driver, is-empty

As developers, we need to integrate the support of the Russian cash register “[Kaznachei](https://xn--80aapgmbx5f.xn--80asehdb/)” into the project. All integration materials are available on the [manufacturer's website](https://integration.atol.ru/api/?utm_referrer=google.com#rpc-server). However, the described scheme does not work. **The atol driver does not accept string parameters as input.** This problem presents only on linux but there is no problem in the windows environment.

Our project has the following **environment**:

- Server: Linux x64 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS without graphical shell
- Project: C# NET.CORE
- The driver is installed from the `libfptr10_10.10.0.0_amd64.deb` package (downloaded from the manufacturer's website https://fs.atol.ru)
- The cash register is connected to a PC accessible over a local network. The `atol-fptr-rpc-server` kit is installed and running on the PC

**Problems**

1. It is not possible to initialize a working instance of the driver specifying the library directory/library path

```
"DriverPath": "/usr/lib/libfptr10.so".
```

An instance of the driver is created only if we submit an empty string to the constructor.
`"DriverPath": "".`

2. The `LIBFPTR_SETTING_REMOTE_SERVER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` and `LIBFPTR_SETTING_REMOTE_SERVER_ADDR` settings are not set from the code. Executing the `fptr.setSingleSetting()` method followed by executing `fptr.applySingleSettings()` does not give a result. We see an empty line in the atol log. If, after executing these methods, we request settings again `fptr.getSettings()` as result we get a standard JSON with default settings:

```
2023.12.11 12:47:22.756       T:E5451640 INFO  [FiscalPrinter] libfptr_get_settings()
2023.12.11 12:47:22.764       T:E5451640 INFO  [FiscalPrinter] Текущие настройки: [{
   "AccessPassword" : "",
   "AutoDisableBluetooth" : false,
   "AutoEnableBluetooth" : true,
   "AutoMeasurementUnit" : false,
   "AutoReconnect" : true,
   "BaudRate" : 115200,
   "Bits" : 8,
   "ComFile" : "1",
   "DocumentsJournalPath" : "",
   "IPAddress" : "192.168.1.10",
   "IPPort" : 5555,
   "InvertCashDrawerStatus" : false,
   "LibraryPath" : "",
   "MACAddress" : "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF",
   "Model" : 500,
   "OfdChannel" : 2,
   "Parity" : 0,
   "Port" : 1,
   "RemoteServerAddr" : "",
   "RemoteServerConnectionTimeout" : 10000,
   "ScriptsPath" : "",
   "SilentReboot" : 0,
   "StopBits" : 0,
   "UsbDevicePath" : "auto",
   "UseDocumentsJournal" : false,
   "UserPassword" : "",
   "ValidateMarksWithFnmOnly" : false
}
```

3. If we request settings, then try to change any settings, and request settings again, we get an error:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

4. Without correctly setting of the `libfptr10` driver, we get the expected error:

```
2023.12.07 12:04:45.470       T:B12B0640 ERROR [USB] Не удалось найти устройство 2912:FFFF
2023.12.07 12:04:45.476       T:B12B0640 ERROR [FiscalPrinter] Объекту 0xA002B6D0 присвоен код ошибки 4 [Порт недоступен]
```

**As a result**
We are unable to initialize the `libfptr10` driver on the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server according to the description from the official manufacturer's documentation.

- We tried to roll back the version of the installed driver to 10.9.5.0.
- We tried to connect the Kaznachei via the linux usbip utility.
- We decided that the problem was related to the encoding of string parameters and changed the encoding options.
- We thought that the width of the character in bytes 2 or 4 mattered, we tried to change it.

There is no result

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by replacing the library `Atol.Drivers10.Fptr.dll` for an older version `10.9.5.0`. It can be argued that the current version `10.10.0.0` of this library does not work correctly in a linux environment. Hooray